# ErrorException: md5_file(/tmp/phptdn2a80.30601700 1609791282): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel

In my controller I have written code that saves a file. The code is written in my `store()` method and it looks like this:

```
 if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->file('image'); //request the file
            $fileName = md5_file($image . microtime()) . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension(); //use md5 for security reasons and get the extension.
            $image->storeAs('', $fileName, 'public'); //store the file in the public folder disk.

            $assortment->image_path = $fileName;
            $assortment->save();
        }
```

When I run the test I have written I get the following error:

`ErrorException: md5_file(/tmp/phptdn2a80.30601700 1609791282): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.

I know this has to do with my controller and not my test. Does anyone know how I can fix it. I tried not using `md5_file()` by doing this:

`$fileName = uniqid(microtime()) . ".{$image->getClientOriginalExtension()}";`.
This did not work. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Surprisingly, `md5_file()` assumes that the parameter you give it is a filename which it will try to open and hash the contents of. If you just want to hash the string parameter use `md5()`. Also, you probably want `microtime(true)` so that it returns a float instead of an array which will actually cast to a string relatively properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`md5_file()` calculates the md5 hash of a given file. You are giving a wrong file path which is `/tmp/phptdn2a80.30601700 1609791282`.
Maybe you intended to write something like this:

```
$fileName = md5_file($image) . microtime(). '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

**PS about `microtime()`**:
It may not be a good idea to include more than one dot(.) and empty spaces in your files paths. Use microtime carefully by looking below explanations.

`microtime()` has two usages:

1. `microtime(false)` which returns a string like `0.91979600 1609794139`
2. `microtime(true)` which returns a float like `1609794139.9197`

The default `microtime()` usage works like `microtime(false)` which returns a string like `0.91979600 1609794139`

As a result, you are creating a file name like `/tmp/filename.ext0.91979600 1609794139`

Hope this solves your problem.